# Tersest regex for a letter

Tags: java, regex

Just wondering what the briefest way of specifying a letter in regex (in java) is, as measured by the number of characters in the regex. For example, `\w` doesn't work, because it includes numbers and the underscore.

Here are a couple of options:

- `\p{Alpha}`
- `[a-zA-Z]`

Is there anything shorter? It comes up so often that it would be good to know.

Comment: If you make the regex case-insensitive, you could do `[a-z]`

Comment: Offtopic: I don't know why people are crazy about short code. Are there any real advantages?

Comment: @Nambari I have always believed that less code is good, as long as it remains readable for many reasons, but ease of reading and less places for bugs to hide are the two main ones. Less regex is easier to read too.

Comment: @Bohemian: In this case I agree. Short Regex are more easier to read, no offense, but most of your questions/answers revolve around shortest code which made me to make that comment. Good luck.

Comment: @Nambari you are right about me being a fan of short code. I have noticed a strong correlation between inexperience and volume of code. Conversely, skill and experience yields the briefest and best code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
\pL
```

It matches a Unicode letter.

The following expression matches only `[a-zA-Z]` and it has only eight characters, but the backslashes need to be escaped inside a Java string literal, which will increase the character count to 10.

```
[^\PL\W]
```

Comment: Not cheating, but "not in the spirit of the question". Sometimes you don't have the opportunity to create a `Pattern` (eg when passing a regex as a parameter). Not a bad answer though :)

Comment: Gee - we're splitting hairs now, but this is a `java` question, so the regex *String* would be longer for you option #2, but I do like that one better

Comment: We have a winner! Very nice. Interestingly, the regex `\pL` is not mentioned directly in `Pattern` javadoc, although `\p{Lu}` is (uppercase letters)

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I can think of:

```
(?i)[a-z]
```

However, this turns the `case-insensitive` switch on for the remainder of the regex, so if the rest of the regex needs to be case *sensitive*, you would need to turn the switch off again:

```
(?i)[a-z](?-i)
```

Which then makes it *longer* than `[a-zA-Z]`.

So this answer is *possibly* the shortest, if it suits the situation.

Comment: ?  even `(?i)[a-z]` is already longer than `[a-zA-Z]`.  For curiosity’s sake, does java support `(?i:[a-z])` (turning on i for a limited scope?)

Comment: @ysth Yes: `"a".matches("(?i:[A-Z])")` is `true`